# Is there a way to tell when a site is created and ready to use when creating it using powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-collection, site

I'm creating a number of sites using a powershell script. Now, when each of the sites is finished, I want to activate features on it.

My problem is that when I do this, it takes some time before the site is ready. Especially in SharePoint Online it is hard to predict when the site is ready. I've tried using time-loops, but I was wondering if there is a status setting somewhere that I can query instead.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we solved the problem. The siteCreationOperation has a property named isComplete. Iterate over this and pick up the boolean for further processing :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.createsite(v=office.15).aspx

```
#Create the site using the properties
$tenant.CreateSite($properties) | Out-Null
...
...
$siteCreationOperation = $tenant.CreateSite($properties)
$ctx.Load($siteCreationOperation)
...
...
#Create the site in the tennancy
...
...
do
{
    ...
    ...
    $ctx.Load($siteCreationOperation)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host $siteCreationOperation.IsComplete
    ...
    ...
}
...
while (!$siteCreationOperation.IsComplete)
...
```